# Loop in a List of elements in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am brand new in data science and I am trying to do some things and it is taking me really long time to realize. I have a list of 6600 list elements, that contain a vector of characters of diverse length (codons). Every list has a name, which corresponds to a particular gene.

The list looks like this:

```
GenesSplitted_________list[6600]_______List of length 6600
_____YBOR24W__________list[330]________Liost of length 330
```

and so on.

Every element of the list looks like this

```
GeneSplitted[[1]]

[[1]]
[1] "ATG"

[[2]]
[1] "TTG"

[[3]]
[1] "AAT"

[[4]]
[1] "AGT"

[[5]]
[1] "TCA
```

and so on.

The task is to apply a loop ion where I can transform every element of the list into data frames.
When I extract one element of the list and I apply this code it seems to work:

```
a <- as.matrix(GenesSplitted[[1]]) #first element of the list into matrix
a <- as.data.frame(Gene1) #transformed into dataframe
a$transcript <- df[1,1] # assign a new column named 
                        # transcript with the name 
                        # indicated in another data frame 
                        # with the gene name
```

When I do this code I get what I expect, which basically looks like this:

```
1   ATG YBR024W
2   TTG YBR024W
3   AAT YBR024W
4   AGT YBR024W
5   TCA YBR024W
6   AGA YBR024W
7   AAA YBR024W
8   TAT YBR024W
```

and so on.

Then I try to do the loop over the list. I created an empty list with 6600 elements that I pretend to fill in while looping.

```
GenesSplittedFrames <- vector(mode = "list", length = 6600) #Empty list for the frames

z<- 1
for (frame in GenesSplitted[[]]){
  a <- as.matrix(GenesSplitted[[frame]])
  b <- as.data.frame(a)
  b$transcript <- df[z,1]
  print(b)
  z <- z+1
}
```

Nevertheless, I am not able to get what I expect, and I have been doing loops like this one before in R.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Try `for (frame in GenesSplitted)` with no `[[` which are only used when subsetting, followed by `as.matrix(frame)`. Each `frame` is an *element* of `GenesSplitted`, not an *index* into that list.

Comment: Thanks a million!!!!, I will give it a try and I will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not tested, since there is no data in reproducible form but for what I can understand of the question it might work.

```
# Create an empty list for the frames
GenesSplittedFrames <- vector(mode = "list", length = 6600) 

for (frame_inx in seq_along(GenesSplitted)){
  a <- as.matrix(GenesSplitted[[frame_inx]])
  b <- as.data.frame(a)
  b$transcript <- df[frame_inx, 1]
  print(b)
  GenesSplittedFrames[[frame_inx]] <- b
}
```